# $\frac{1}{x}$ function without the asymptote?

Tags: exponential-function

I'm not very good at math and I need to use a function which gives me high values for low inputs and low outputs for high inputs. From the graph of the $\frac{1}{x}$ it looks kind of like what I want but I need the function without the asymptote. My input values will also be between $0$ and $1$. 
I will also need to make my output between $0$ and $1$.
Any help?
I need it for an image processing project.

Thanks

Comment: What value do you want it to be for $x=0$? Because if you want it to be higher and higher without limit as $x$ gets down to $0$, then it has an asymptote.

Comment: I'd like it to be 0 actually. If that's possible. I'm trying to make a function to bump up the saturation channel of an HSV image.

Comment: Something like $y=x^2$? It's $0$ at $x=0$and $1$ at $x=1$. But that doesn't fulfil your question's condition.

Comment: $1-x$ works.  If you want more extreme behavior, use $(1-x)^n$ for some appropriate value of $n.$

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to modify that to help me. It's not exactly what I want.

Comment: 1-x doesn't work because it needs to be 0 for 0.

Comment: That's a low output for a low input, i.e. the opposite of what you said you want, though

Comment: @user3927312 Maybe $y=0$ for $x=0$ and $y=1-x$ for $x>0$?

Comment: @dbx It is, but it seems more like a special case to me the rest of the function should follow what I stated in the question though.

Comment: @user3927312 If it doesn't need to be continuous, then my function above would work.

Comment: I'm trying it out.